# How to set HttpMessageHandler on Flurl calls globally without calling Configure()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, flurl

I'm building a small library for internal use that relies on Flurl for handling all outgoing HTTP calls.

I want to provide the ability for consumers of this library to opt-in to our HTTP call tracing infrastrucure like so:

Startup.cs:

```
... 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    services.AddTracing(options => ...);
    ....
}

...
```

My current implementation of `AddTracing()` looks like this:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTracing(this IServiceCollection services, Action<TracingOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        var tracingOptions = new TracingOptions();
        configureOptions(tracingOptions);

        // Make these options available in DI container
        services.AddSingleton(tracingOptions);

        FlurlHttp.Configure(settings =>
        {
            settings.HttpClientFactory = new TracingHttpClientFactory(tracingOptions.ApplicationName);
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

And the current implementation of `TracingHttpClientFactory` looks like this:

```
public class TracingHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly string _applicationName;

    public TracingHttpClientFactory(string applicationName)
    {
        _applicationName = applicationName;
    }

    // override to customize how HttpMessageHandler is created/configured
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        var tracingHandler = new TracingHandler(_applicationName, base.CreateMessageHandler());

        return tracingHandler;
    }
}
```

This works, but the issue I'm facing is that the documentation for `Configure()` reads: *Should only be called once at application startup.*

As a result, I've "wasted" my call to `Configure()` by adding tracing (which is optional). In scenarios where tracing is used, I also still need to call `Configure()` afterwards.

An example of when I might need to call configure afterwards would be in Startup.cs:

```
... 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    // Configure() is being called inside AddTracing()
    services.AddTracing(options => ...);
    ....
    // This is a second call to Configure()
    FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => {
        var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
        };
        settings.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(jsonSettings);
    });
}
...
```

Point being - each consumer of `AddTracing()` should be able to configure Flurl as they see fit. The point of `AddTracing()` is to simply "supercharge" Flurl with some extra, optional functionality. It isn't meant to take over `Configure()` - it's meant to extend it.

I've been reading through the docs [here](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/), and despite there being a number of places where configuration can occur, I can't work out a way to get my `TracingHandler` (which is a `HttpMessageHander`) into every request without calling `Configure()` somewhere.

Is there a suitable implementation for the scenario I've described?

Comment: "In scenarios where tracing is used, I also still need to call Configure() afterwards." Why? Can you elaborate on that part?

Comment: I've made an edit with additional clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the "call once at startup" advice is it touches global scope. If you start messing with the global settings in lots of different places, perhaps on different threads (e.g. in a controller action method), you could end up with weird race conditions and other unpredictable behavior.

In your case, yes, you're calling `Configure` twice, but the calls are sequential, non-conflicting, and properly done where "startup" code belongs in an ASP.NET Core app. Most importantly, they're done before any calls are made with Flurl. So what you've done here is fine.

Comment: This is very helpful - thanks. This could work for me for now, but I'm immediately picturing some library consumer accidentally overwriting my HttpClientFactory without even knowing they're doing anything wrong. Generally speaking, the tracing library consumers shouldn't know or care what "services.AddTracing()" is doing. I see that you're a primary contributor to Flurl, so I'm sure if there were a better way, you'd have let me know :) Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Keep in mind that `services.AddXXX` methods are typically for adding/configuring injected services, not changing global settings. A "better way" could be to set the factory on injected `FlurlClient`s instead, which is more in line with IoC patterns, but you'd have to tell your users "tracing works when you use an injected client like this" rather than "tracing works everywhere no matter how you use Flurl". Bottom line: if your library can configure Flurl globally, then so could your library's consumers, and I can't envision any way around that other than telling your users "don't do that".

Comment: Yep - makes sense. I was aware I was somewhat abusing AddXXX via this pattern. It's the primary reason I made this post in the first place. Appreciate the feedback.